# Передача переменных по ссылке

Tags: php, ссылки

Здравствуйте, уважаемое сообщество.

Маленький вопросик к знатокам. Часто в своих проектах на php употребляю ссылки на переменные. Например:

```
class zzz {
    public function __construct(&$a, &$b, &$c){
        $this->a = &$a;
        $this->b = &$b;
        $this->c = &$c;
    }
}

class yyy {
    ...
    public function init(){
        $my1 = Array(Array(...), Array(...));
        $my2 = 'Очень длинная строка';
        $my3 = Array('строка 1', ' строка 2');
        new zzz($my1, $my2, $my3);
    }
}
```

или еще вариант:

```
class zzz {
    public function __construct($cls){
        $this->a = &$cls->my1;
        $this->b = &$cls->my2;
        $this->c = &$cls->my3;
    }
}
class yyy {
    public $my1 = Array(Array(...), Array(...));
    public $my2 = 'Очень длинная строка';
    public $my3 = Array('строка 1', ' строка 2');
    ...
    public function init(){
        new zzz($this);
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы узнать, имеет ли писать такое смысл и повлияет это как-то на производительность или нет? Как я понимаю, php, по идее, должен передать просто адрес строки или массива, а само содержимое переменной в памяти копировать не будет. А вот как это на самом деле происходит, понятия не имею... Может в php это все предусмотрено, и он сам какими-то своими внутренними алгоритмами так и делает?

Мне не сложно, конечно, добавить везде "&", но будет ли это хоть мизерно отражаться на времени загрузки страницы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html

Comment: Ясно и понятно) Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Вы не должны думать о производительности на этом этапе. Вопросы производительности нужно решать при возникновении проблем. Подумайте лучше о смысле параметров.

Передача параметра по ссылке означает, что параметр может быт изменён вызываемой процедурой. Это то, чего вы хотите? Если вызываемая процедура не должна ни в коем случае менять значение передаваемой переменной, не нужно и передавать её по ссылке. Также подумайте о том, что в качестве ссылочного параметра вы не сможете передать выражение типа `$n + 1`.

Передача по ссылке означает "параметр имеет право быть изменён вызываемой функцией". Тот, кто будет читать код после вас, вынужден будет предполагать, что такие изменения возможны -- или ему придётся привыкать к вашему нестандартному стилю программирования.

Вы должны думать о читаемости и понимаемости кода, а не искать мизерный выигрыш. Потому что мизерный выигрыш обернётся проблемами при поддержке и масштабировании проекта.

Наверняка передача по ссылке или по значению как-то отражается на времени загрузки страницы, но это всё зависит от версии. Например, в некоторых случаях в C++ раньше рекомендовалось передавать параметры по ссылке, а сейчас -- [по значению](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/).

(Возможно, отдельным случаем является передача больших массивов: проконсультируйтесь со знатоками языка!)

Обязательная [цитата из Кнута](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization):

> Программисты тратят огромное количество времени думая о (или опасаясь насчёт) скорости некритичных участков их программ. Эти попытки достичь эффективности имеют жёстко негативное влияние, когда в рассмотрение входят отладка и поддержка программы. Мы обязаны забыть о мелких оптимизациях, скажем, в 97% времени: **преждевременная оптимизация -- источник всех проблем**. Тем не менее, мы не должны упускать возможности улучшить критические 3%.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Согласен, что на этапе разработки, оптимизация может быть лишней, хотя бы просто потому что код, вообще, потом может быть перевернут наизнанку. Но я то все равно рано или поздно задамся этим вопросом - функции и классы то есть везде, а тратить лишние ресурсы не хочется...

Comment: @Dobby007: Пожалуйста! В момент оптимизации вы найдёте те самые 3% и оптимизируете их. Но только не начинайте раньше времени, пока не установлен bottleneck!

Comment: @Dobby007, вы сначала задумайтесь, сколько времени и ресурсов тратится, например, на соединение с БД, работу с шаблонами или подобные тяжёлые операции. По сравнению с этим передача параметров - детский лепет :)

Comment: @klopp, просто меня всегда мучил вопрос, сколько ресурсов тратится именно на передачу :) теперь буду знать)